# pthread_cleanup_pop error on Windows- make it compilable

Tags: c++, pthreads

Code:

```
    void clean(void *message)
    {
     cout<<"Exiting "<<(char*)message<<endl;
    }
    void *func2(void* arg)
    {
       char *message = "func2";
       pthread_cleanup_push(clean,(void*)message);
       int status;
       int count=0;   
       pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE,&status);
       for(;;){
          if(count%3467==0)
          {
              sleep(3);
              pthread_testcancel();
          }
          else if(count%67==0)
          {
              cout<<"func 2 is running"<<endl;
          }
          else
          {}
          count++;
       }
        pthread_cleanup_pop(0);//error is pointing here
    }
```

When I try to compile this , I am getting an error

```
cancel.cpp:45:5: error: second operand to the conditional operator is of type 'v
oid', but the third operand is neither a throw-expression nor of type 'void'
     pthread_cleanup_pop(cleanup_pop_arg);
```

I am not able to find what's the problem with my code.
Compiled with `g++ file.cpp -pthread` , Windows 8, Cygwin 64.

How to make the code compile successfully?

Edit:

After preprocessing this is how it does look.

```
void *func2(void* arg)
{
    char *message = "func2";
   { const _pthread_cleanup _pthread_cup = {(clean), ((void*)message), *pthread_getclean()}; __sync_synchronize(); *pthread_getclean() = (_pthread_cleanup *) &_pthread_cup; __sync_synchronize();
   int status;
   int count=0;
   pthread_setcancelstate(0x01,&status);
   for(;;){
      if(count%3467==0)
      {
          sleep(3);
          pthread_testcancel();
      }
      else if(count%67==0)
      {
          cout<<"func 2 is running"<<endl;
      }
      else
      {}
      count++;
   }
    (*pthread_getclean() = _pthread_cup.next, (cleanup_pop_arg?_pthread_cup.func((pthread_once_t *)_pthread_cup.arg):0));};

}
```

Comment: The `pthread_cleanup_pop` (and `pthread_cleanup_push`) symbols may be implemented as macros, which is apparently the case here. You might want to look at the preprocessed code to see what the macros expand to and it might give you some hints to what the problem might be.

Comment: How do I check, the expansion of macro?

Comment: Doing `pthread_cleanup_pop(void(0));` might help.

Comment: @alk: error: could not convert '0' from 'void' to 'bool'

Comment: Where does the `bool`come from? And the other error is gone? The code does  compile with the two `pthread_cleanup_*` commented out?